# SQL lite search function

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

So I am new to SQL lite and Python in general...

I'm creating a search function that should return an else statement when the input receives an empty query. Not understanding while I fufill the else statement the whole database is returned instead of the print statement I called.

```
def search_task():
askjeeves =  input("Enter Search Term: ")
cur = con.cursor()
if askjeeves != "" or askjeeves != " ":
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE author LIKE'%'||?||'%' ", (askjeeves,))
    finalsearch = cur.fetchall()
    print(finalsearch)
    search_task()
else:
    print("No value inputted, program ended. ")
```

Also tried:

```
def search_task():
askjeeves =  input("Enter Search Term: ")
cur = con.cursor()
if askjeeves != None:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE author LIKE'%'||?||'%' ", (askjeeves,))
    finalsearch = cur.fetchall()
    print(finalsearch)
    search_task()
else:
    print("No search input")
    input("Do you want to search again? Input 1 for Yes, 0 for No:")
    if input == 1:
        search_task()
    else:
        print("Search Ended")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency here.  You are calling the function again in the if.
When it is empty, you have a problem with your checks.
Empty strings in python are False. So

```
def search_task():
   askjeeves =  input("Enter Search Term: ")
   cur = con.cursor()
   if askjeeves and askjeeves != " ":
      cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE author LIKE'%'||?||'%' ", (askjeeves,))
      finalsearch = cur.fetchall()
      print(finalsearch)
      search_task()
   else:
      print("No search input")

input("Do you want to search again? Input 1 for Yes, 0 for No:")
if input == 1:
   search_task()
else:
   print("Search Ended")
```